# Android questions more active on Stack Overflow than on Android.SE

Tags: discussion, scope, stack-exchange

Shouldn't Android related questions be posted on  https://android.stackexchange.com/?

Isn't that what the site is about? Because Android questions are way more active on Stack Overflow than on Android.SE.

Comment: There's no automatic migration, the only thing you can do is to suggest people asking rather there.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: this isn't even about migration, the OP misunderstands what Android.SE is about.

Comment: Kudos for asking about this, presumably before just posting a question on one or the other. When there seem to be conflicts between sites, reading their respective help centers can be good.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Android.SE is a site for **end users** of Android. Android development questions are expressly [off topic there](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and should be asked on Stack Overflow.

Vice versa, you cannot post questions on [*how to use the Android Contacts application*](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contacts) here on Stack Overflow for example; that's not a programming problem.

TLDR: The two sites have very distinct topic areas and you cannot compare their activity.

Comment: oh, i see. I didn't realize it is for end users.

Comment: @HusseinShehady: **always** check the other site help center to see what a site is about.